# There's an error in my Java Program about entering name and gender. Number of Male and Female is counted and printed and it repeats process

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

The procedure of this code must be looping until 1000 applicants enter their name and gender but it stopped at the first applicant. Please help me find out what's going on. I tried different ways but it didn't work.

Here's the code:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem5 {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {  
       Scanner myVar = new Scanner (System.in);
       int b = 1000;
       String [] name = new String [b];
       /*enter name and gender of applicants*/
       for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++)
       {
           int index = i;
           System.out.println("Enter name of applicant and gender:");
           System.out.println("M for male and F for female");
           name[index] = myVar.nextLine();
           
           for (String name1:name)
           {
               int maleCount = 0;
               int femaleCount = 0;
               if (name1.contains("M")) 
               {
                   maleCount++;
               } 
               if (name1.contains("F")) 
               {
                   femaleCount++;
               }
               System.out.println("NUMBER OF MALE: "+maleCount);
               System.out.println("NUMBER OF FEMALE: "+femaleCount);
           }
         }
       }
    }
```

The result must look like this.
For example, I type my name Isabella Cruz and my gender F.

```
Enter name of applicant and gender:
M for male and F for female
Isabella Cruz F
NUMBER OF MALE: 0
NUMBER OF FEMALE: 1
```

But, it stops there and an error came:
 **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Problem5.main(Problem5.java:30)**

I need solutions for this, please.

Comment: Which line corresponds to line 30 ?

Comment: The if statement one: if (name1.contains("M"))

Comment: Little tip: renaming your array to names and name1 to name makes your code a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` has `"Isabella Cruz F"` in index `0` and the rest of the array is `null`s, so  `name1` is `null` in the second iteration. Take the second loop out of the first one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    //...
}

for (String name1 : name) {
   //...
}
```

You can also use only one loop and get the data there

```
int maleCount = 0;
int femaleCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    System.out.println("Enter name of applicant and gender:");
    System.out.println("M for male and F for female");
    name[index] = myVar.nextLine();

    if (name[index].contains("M")) {
        maleCount++;
    } 
    else if (name[index].contains("F")) {
        femaleCount++;
    }
}

System.out.println("NUMBER OF MALE: " + maleCount);
System.out.println("NUMBER OF FEMALE: " + femaleCount);
```

Comment: @YuraVictoria See my update, it should be what you are looking for, Just put the prints inside the loop.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

There is couple issues. First is there is a nested for loop. I see that you are populating the String array first then iterating over it to check for the count. You really only need one loop. Second is that you are checking if the String contains "M" or "F" which may be problematic if the persons name contains that String(Ex Joanna M Smith F). You only need to check the last character.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem5 {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner myVar = new Scanner (System.in);
        int b = 1000;
        String [] names = new String [b];
        int maleCount = 0;
        int femaleCount = 0;
        /*enter name and gender of applicants*/
        for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name of applicant and gender:");
            System.out.println("M for male and F for female");
            String line = myVar.nextLine();
            names[i] = line;

            // check if the line passed in is a M or F

            if (line.substring(line.length()-1).equals("M"))
            {
                maleCount++;
            }
            if (line.substring(line.length()-1).equals("F"))
            {
                femaleCount++;
            }
            System.out.println("NUMBER OF MALE: "+maleCount);
            System.out.println("NUMBER OF FEMALE: "+femaleCount);
        }
    }
}
```